# Is there a way to end program if two specific words are not typed?

Tags: c

Good Morning,

For some reason, when the user types 'google' it displays the bottom part "No applications entered" when it shouldnt.

Already tried putting an else statement in there and this still does not work.

`

```
     while (1) {
     printf("What program would you like to open, %s?\n", name);
      scanf("%s", input);

 if (strcmp(input,"google") == 0){
 printf("Opening Google Chrome for you!\n");
ShellExecute(NULL, "open","chrome.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
printf("Done!\n");}

 if (strcmp(input,"outlook") == 0){
 printf("Opening Microsoft Outlook for you!\n");
ShellExecute(NULL, "open","Outlook.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
printf("Done\n");}

 if (strcmp(input,"putty") == 0){
 printf("Opening Putty for you!\n");
ShellExecute(NULL, "open","Putty.exe",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
printf("Done\n");}

else{
if(input < 0 || input > 0){
printf("no program entered, please enter another program\n");}
}
```

`
I'd expect the program to not display the error if it matches 'google' but it still does. Doesnt work for any of the other input variables shown though.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting. In this case it's pretty obvious why indentation matters.

Comment: This question should not be edited to include the indentation as it is pertinent to the problem. The OP's original code has been restored.

Answer (score 4):

Had you indented your code correctly, the problem would become obvious:

```
while (1)
{
    printf("What program would you like to open, %s?\n", name);
    scanf("%s", input);

    if (strcmp(input, "google") == 0)
    {
        printf("Opening Google Chrome for you!\n");
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "chrome.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        printf("Done!\n");
    }

    if (strcmp(input, "outlook") == 0)
    {
        printf("Opening Microsoft Outlook for you!\n");
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "Outlook.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        printf("Done\n");
    }

    if (strcmp(input, "putty") == 0)
    {
        printf("Opening Putty for you!\n");
        ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "Putty.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        printf("Done\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (input < 0 || input > 0)
        {
            printf("no program entered, please enter another program\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem becomes very clear - the `else` applies ONLY to the last `if` statement.

Instead of the above, implement `else if` in the code to ensure that the final `else` applies only if ANY of the other conditions are not met.

Comment: Be that as it may, this is why we should prompt the OP to fix their indention before answering their question.

Comment: @Lundin I agree totally and that is why I have voted to close the question for being a simple typographical error

Comment: It's pretty strange to close vote a question while at the same time answering it though.